# Lily58 OLED getting borked

Tags: qmk-firmware, qmk

I'm working on a keymap for the [Lily58](https://github.com/kata0510/Lily58) that has a built in [Pomodoro timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) ([repository here](https://github.com/CaseyB/qmk_firmware/tree/pomodoro/keyboards/lily58/keymaps/pomodoro)).

I'm running into issues showing images on the [OLED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED). I have three bitmaps that represent the different "screens" I want to show. I `memcpy` the first one into a display buffer in `keyboard_post_init_user` and then blit that to the OLED using `oled_write_raw` in `oled_task_user`. That works fine. I can show all three screens that way.

[[image: Splash Screen][[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtrdQ.jpg)

[image: Work Screen]

[image: Rest Screen]

The problem is when I try to switch between the screens. I use an [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) call to update the state of the timer on the slave board and in that function I do another `memcpy` to load the new bitmap into the display buffer. But as soon as I do that it totally borks both displays, which I don't understand.

[image: Borked OLEDs]

Here's the code that does the initial *[memcpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Functions)*:

```c
void keyboard_post_init_user(void) {
     transaction_register_rpc(SYNC_POMODORO_STATE, set_slave_pomodoro_state);
     memcpy(header, headerBase, HEADER_SIZE);
     memcpy(statusDisplay, logoBase, STATUS_SIZE);
}
```

And the code that updates the OLED display:

```c
bool oled_task_user(void) {
    if (is_keyboard_master()) {
        oled_write_ln(read_layer_state(), false);
        oled_write_ln(read_pomodoro_state(), false);
    } else {
        update_pomodoro_display();
    }
    return false;
}

void update_pomodoro_display(void) {
    // oled_clear();
    oled_set_cursor(0, 0);
    oled_write_raw(header, HEADER_SIZE);
    oled_set_cursor(0, 1);
    oled_write_raw(statusDisplay, STATUS_SIZE);
}
```

This is the code that I'm trying to add, but it messes up the display so I have it commented out.

```c
void set_slave_pomodoro_state(uint8_t in_buflen, const void *in_data, uint8_t out_buflen, void *out_data) {
    state = *(pomo_state*)in_data;
    // if (state == _WORK) {
    //     memcpy(statusDisplay, workBase, STATUS_SIZE);
    // } else if (state == _REST) {
    //     memcpy(statusDisplay, restBase, STATUS_SIZE);
    // }
}
```

Where should I look?